# Let X be a non-empty set and U an ultrafilter over X....

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, filters

Let X be a non-empty set and U an ultrafilter over X. Show that if X = $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup… \cup A_n$, then there is k $\in$ {1,…, n} such that $A_K \in$ U.

---

X = $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup… \cup A_n$ = $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \in U$, since U is an utrafilter, k $\leq$ n  and n is finite then $a_k \in U$.

I don't think this is good, but I can't think of another way to show it. It is not trivial that $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup… \cup A_n \in U$ then $A_k \in U$ where k $\in$ {1,...,n}.

maybe I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that no $A_k$ belongs to $U$. Then $X\setminus A_k\in U$ for all $k$, since $U$ is an ultrafilter. Filters are closed under finite intersections, so $$\bigcap_{k=1}^n (X\setminus A_k)\in U,$$ but that intersection is empty because the $A_i$ cover $X$, which is a contradiction, since the empty set is not in any ultrafilter.